# Removing empty List in output as result

Tags: scripting, python

I have a simple script as following:

```
import re
wanted_line = []
with open('lines.txt','rt') as myfile:
   for myline in myfile:
   wanted_line = re.findall('ticket/\d+',myline)
    print(wanted_line[:-1])
```

by this code i am reading a file, and looking for a line which includes a url, and in the url looking for a digit, which is my ticketid.

the script works correctly, but as result, it returns other lines as empty list as below:

```
[]
[]
['ticket/1675']
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

This while i am just looking for:

> ['ticket/1675'] as my desired output.

Comment: OK, got the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the print in a condition check

```
if len(wanted_line[:-1]) > 0:
    print(wanted_line[:-1])
```